# C# TPL how to know that all tasks are done?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have the Loop which generates tasks.

Code:

```
Task task = null;
foreach (Entity a in AAAA)
{
  // create the task 
  task = new Task(() => {
    myMethod(a);
  },  Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);
  task.Start();
}
```

As you can see in each iteration task object has new initialization (..new Task(() =>..)
    How can I know that all tasks done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I f you replace this with a

```
 Parallel.ForEach(...,  () => myMethod(a), ...)
```

Then you get an automatic Wait on all tasks at the end of the ForEach.

And maybe run the ForEach from a separate Task.

Comment: Beat me to it. Wish I could upvote several times. This is after all a good example of "don't reinvent the wheel"

Comment: The thing is, there are some very real performance concerns/difference between a loop that creates tasks, and Parallel.ForEach.  While they can be similar in many cases, they should not be blindly substituted for one another to solve unrelated problems.

Comment: @Andrew, you are right. I just blinked over it because of the non-specific 'mymethod(a)` and lack of information about the circumstances.

Answer (score 13):

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (Entity a in AAAA)
{
  // create the task 
  task = new Task(() => {
    myMethod(a);
  },  Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);

  // Add the tasks to a list
  allTasks.Add(task);
  task.Start();
}

// Wait until all tasks are completed.
Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Neat - I think you'll need to type the list `List<Task>`, though, so that the `.ToArray()` generates an array of Tasks not objects

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to keep references to all the tasks created in the loop. Then you can use the `Task.WaitAll` method (see [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx)). You can either create an array and assign tasks to elements of the array (in C# 2.0) or you can use LINQ:

```
var tasks = 
   AAAA.Select((Entity a) => 
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { myMethod(a); },
         Token, TaskCreationOptions.None)).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks)
```

If you don't need to use tasks (explicitly) then Henk's suggestion to use `Parallel.ForEach` is probably a better option.